# Need my character's hands to move independently from HIPS bone

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm animating a character and at some point I need his hands to move independently from the hips bone (as to say: not following the hips bone when I move it).
Is it possible to add a setting to the IK rig that could let me switch from having the two bones connected and not having them whenever I need?

Hoping have made myself clear!

Comment: If your IK hands are parented to the hip bone (as I understand it) and you want to turn this relationship on/off, you need to make this with Child_Of constraint and animate it's influence.

Comment: @Jerryno. Thanks. Can you explain this in other way? I try to move one shoe from MakeHuman model.